# Shut down a ATL application cleanly

Tags: c++, atl, exit-handler

I have developed a console ATL application and want to trap the close?, exit?, terminate? event so that I can close log files and perform a general clean-up on exit.

How can I trap the 'terminate' event that would result from someone ending the .exe in the task manager?

**EDIT:**

It's a console application, I've attached the main class. Could you possibly point to where and how I should use `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`?

```
// Override CAtlExeModuleT members
int WinMain(int nShowCmd) throw()
{   
    if (CAtlBaseModule::m_bInitFailed) //ctor failed somewhere
    {
        ATLASSERT(0);
        return -1;
    }

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    LPTSTR lpCmdLine = GetCommandLine(); //this line necessary for _ATL_MIN_CRT

    if( ParseCommandLine( lpCmdLine, &hr ) )
    {
        if( SUCCEEDED( RegisterClassObjects( CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE ) ) )
        {
            CComPtr<IRORCAdapterMain> pAdapter;

            if( SUCCEEDED( pAdapter.CoCreateInstance( L"RORCAdapter.RORCAdapterMain" ) ) )
            {
                if( SUCCEEDED( pAdapter->StartAdapter() ) )
                {
                    MSG msg;

                    while( GetMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0 ) )
                        DispatchMessage( &msg );
                }
            }

            RevokeClassObjects();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is actually about ATL, not C++; consider changing the title of your question...

Comment: **<comment from deleted answer>** You have a message pump there, when you get a WM_QUIT is should exit from the while loop. Also check GetMessage documentation because your message loop has a possible bug.

Answer (score 4):

You can't trap "End Process" from the Processes tab in Task Manager. If a program could trap it, how would you kill it?

To respond to "End Process" on the Applications tab in Task Manager, handle the WM_CLOSE message in your main window.

This assumes that your ATL app is a Windows GUI application. If it's a console application, you need to look at SetConsoleCtrlHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Catching Ctrl-C / Ctrl-Break is not to hard.
Just call SetConsoleCtrlHandler to specify which call-back function should handle it.

(Hopefully) illustrating example:

```
#include <wincon.h>

bool g_terminate = false;

int main(void)
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler( control_handler, TRUE );

    while ( !g_terminate )
    {
       doWork();
    }    
}


int WINAPI control_handler ( DWORD dwCtrlType )
{
    switch( dwCtrlType )
    {
        case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:  
        case CTRL_C_EVENT:      
            g_terminate = true;
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

/L

Answer (score 0):

Off course, to have you example terminating, in control_handler replace

```
g_terminate = true;
```

with

```
PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
```